# Проверить правильность составление таблиц

Tags: sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE [Reader] (
    Kod_Readera int NOT NULL,
    FIO varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Adress varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Phone int NOT NULL,
    Number_Bileta int NOT NULL,
    Otmetka_vybytii varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_READER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [Kod_Readera] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [Book] (
    Kod_knigi int NOT NULL,
    Rik_Vydannya date NOT NULL,
    Nazva varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Avtor varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Kilkist_ekzemplyariv int NOT NULL,
    Tsina int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_BOOK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [Kod_knigi] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [Knyha_Vydana] (
    kod_vydachi int NOT NULL,
    Data_vydachi date NOT NULL,
    Realna_Data_povernennya date NOT NULL,
    Planova_data_povernennya date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_KNYHA_VYDANA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [kod_vydachi] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
ALTER TABLE [Reader] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Reader_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Kod_Readera]) REFERENCES [Knyha_Vydana]([kod_vydachi])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [Reader] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Reader_fk0]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Book] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Book_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Kod_knigi]) REFERENCES [Knyha_Vydana]([kod_vydachi])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [Book] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Book_fk0]
GO
```

Просто проверьте, правильно ли я написал код по первой схеме

Comment: Типы данных на потолке подсмотрел? ну и нормализация - где? Плюс - одинаковых книг несколько, а читатель берёт только одну...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишу несколько замечаний по вашей схеме и реализации

1. Вы по вашей схеме. Если вы хотите реализовать схему много ко многим по 3 таблицам то в промежуточной таблице будут идентификаторы смежных таблиц

   Reader (id) -> Knyha_Vydana (id, reader_id, book_id) -> book (id)
2. Вы должны определиться с [наймингом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft). Либо [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (PascalCase -  UpperCamelCase, Lower), [SnakeCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (Upper, Lower), KebabCase.
3. Не мешайте языки является дурным тоном, остановитесь на одном выбранном язык: Knyha_Vydana, Reader, Otmetka_vybytii, Book. Ничего против русского языка не имею но транслитерация будет вам мешать в будущем поскольку это не русский и не английский.